# Variable scope of this in Javascript SpiderMonkey

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, spidermonkey

I'm using SpiderMonkey Javascript Engine for a game in COCOS2d.
Basically I cannot understand exactly the scope of this in Javascript Spidermonkey. Does Spidermonkey use a different kind of Javascript. Or may be simple I'm weak with javascript ?

Let me explain: This is a class:

```
var mainLayer = cc.Layer.extend({ 
    genericArray : null,

    constructor: function () {
         this.genericArray = new Array();
         this.genericArray[0] = new TestObject();
    },

    onTouched : function() {
         this.genericArray[0].testme(); // THIS FAILS WITH SPIDERMONKEY, WORKS WITH ANY OTHER BROWSER
    }
}
```

It tells to me that the Object is not instanciated. But I did it in the contructor. I fear that the problem is in how this is interpreted in the onTouched function.
Any suggestion ?

```
    var mainLayer = cc.Layer.extend({ 
    genericArray : null,

    constructor: function () {
         this.genericArray = new Array();
         this.genericArray[0] = new TestObject();
    },

    onTouched : function() {
        var genericArray = new Array();
        genericArray[0] = new TestObject();
        genericArray[0].testme(); // THIS WORKS CORRECTLY BOTH ON SPIDERMONKEY AND ON THE BROSWSER, BUT IS NOT WHAT I NEED!
    }
}
```